# Generating an html documentation in Eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I wan to generate an html documentation for my code, but my eclipse INDIGO seems to lack Server options to add the apache tomcat, do I have to install another version of Eclipse or there are another ways to generate html from it?

Comment: What is "an html documentation"?  Javadoc?  Something else?  Do you have Javadoc comments in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no clue what your problem is. Consider rephrasing it.